# Using std::is_convertible with std::type_index

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an vector of `std::type_index`, which indicate the trait types that a particular node has. I'm implementing a function which checks whether the node supports a particular type. It looks like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::type_index> traits;

...

template <typename T>
bool hasTrait() {
    return std::find(traits.begin(), traits.end(), typeid(T)) != traits.end();
}
```

However, this won't work if type `T` is a derived type of some base type in traits. In order to fix this problem, I wanted to use `std::is_convertible`.

However, I only have access to the `std::type_index` of the type, so I can't do that. Something like this would be required: `std::is_convertible<traitTypeIndex::type, T>`

Comment: Why not just add all the derived types' `type_index`s to the vector?

Comment: Because as far as I know there's no easy way to do this. Suppose base class A, and the following inheritance chain A -> B -> C -> D. Suppose C is on the traits list. I'd like the function to match A, B, and C, but not D. I would have to somehow figure out a way to decompose C into A and B and add all three to the vector list.

Comment: Is it unacceptable to pass all A, B and C to the variadic template parameter, `template<class... T> bool hasTraits() { /* do check */ }` and `hasTraits<A,B,C>()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would mention that it is surely impossible with `std::is_convertible`. Like all other things from `type_traits`, `std::is_convertible`is a purely compile-time thing. But you want it to give you answer during the run-time for some run-time argument (which is type_index).

The second question is if this check can be implemented at all for arbitrary polymorphic types (by "arbitrary" I mean that you don't have any specific design-time or run-time information). I think that it's not impossible because the whole run-time reflection we have in C++ is `dynamic_cast` (when RTTI is on). However, even in `dynamic_cast` we have one semi-dynamic argument (pointer or reference) and one static (type to which we wan't to convert). I write `semi-dynamic` because it needs to be a pointer or reference to some certain type, it cannot absolutely type-erased argument (like `void*`). I believe that to check dynamically if one of two types is the inheritor of the other one we need more support from a run-time.

Comment: A shame, but interesting. Thank you – perhaps I will have to include some sort of std::type_index corresponding to a particular server (since those will not be inherited) in the trait and in the node.